# Angular 6 Using Two Shared Module : Component is not a known element:

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, lazy-loading, angularjs-ng-model

I have two shared Moduled 'shared-candidate-login-reg.module.ts' and 'shared.module.ts', I am importing both the shared modules in my home page.  I want to use 'AlertLblComponent' from my 'shared.module.ts' in side my 'WidgetLogRegComponent' component (which is a child component of my home page and also is a part of my 'shared-candidate-login-reg.module'). I am also using Lazy loading. Why can't I get the 'alert-lbl' component in my Home Module?

My alert.module.ts

```
import { AlertLblComponent } from './../directives';
import { AlertService } from './../services/alert.service';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AlertLblComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        AlertService,
    ],
    exports: [
        CommonModule,
        AlertLblComponent
    ]    
  })
  export class SharedModule {}
```

shared-candidate-login-reg.module.ts

```
import { WidgetLogRegComponent } from './../candidates/widget-log-reg/widget-log-reg.component';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    WidgetLogRegComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    WidgetLogRegComponent 
 ]
})
export class ShareCandidateLoginRegdModule { }
```

home.module.ts

```
import {ShareCandidateLoginRegdModule} from './../shared/shared-candidate-login-reg.module';
import {SharedModule} from './../shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent
      ], 
  providers: [CandidateService,JobService],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    ShareCandidateLoginRegdModule,
    HomeRoutingModule,
  ],
  exports: [HomeComponent],

})
export class HomeModule { }
```

home.component.html

```
<div class="col-md-4 banner-form">
  <app-widget-log-reg></app-widget-log-reg>
 </div>
```

widget-log-reg.component.html

```
<alert-lbl></alert-lbl>
<div class="page-tab">
   <div id="form-login">
    ......
   </div>
</div>
```

alert-lbl.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { AlertService } from './../services';

@Component({
    selector: 'alert-lbl',
    templateUrl: 'alert-lbl.component.html'
})
export class AlertLblComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private subscription: Subscription;
    message: any;
    constructor(private alertService: AlertService) { }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this.alertService.getMessage().subscribe(message => { 
            this.message = message; 
        });
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

alert-lbl.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="message" [ngClass]="{ 'alert': message, 'alert-success': message.type === 'success', 'alert-danger': message.type === 'error' }">{{message.text}}</div>
```

I am getting this error fallowing:

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'alert-lbl' is not a known element:
```

Comment: Can you add your AlertLblComponent code? It looks like you put that in a directory called directives, which will behave differently.

Comment: i have added @OneLunchMan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not import `SharedModule` which exports `alert-lbl` component within `ShareCandidateLoginRegdModule`. Just import it as follows

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule // <-- import shared module here
  ],
  declarations: [
    WidgetLogRegComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    WidgetLogRegComponent 
 ]
})
export class ShareCandidateLoginRegdModule { }
```

Comment: Great its woking, but why its not working when i imported separately ?

Comment: If you want to use a component from another module, you have to import it. Unfortunately, there is no global import for components/directives/pipes. Even though you import both of those module within `home.module`, `ShareCandidateLoginRegdModule ` cannot use components from `SharedModule` without importing it.